# Can't unit test styled component that's overriding material-ui

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, styled-components

I have a styled component for a navigational list item that's wrapping a Material-UI list item, and using the '&&' in order to override the styles without using the '!important' flags.

```
import { ListItem } from 'material-ui/List'

export const StyledNavListItem = withTheme()(styled(ListItem)`
  && {
    background: ${props => props.selected
    ? props.theme.palette.backgrounds.selected
    : 'inherit'};
  }
`)
```

It's implemented as such:

```
export const NavListItem = props => {
  return (
    <StyledNavListItem selected={props.selected} component={Link} to={props.to || ''} onClick={props.onClick || (() => false)} button>
      {props.icon && <ListItemIcon><Icon name={props.icon} /></ListItemIcon>}
      <ListItemText primary={props.children || ''} />
    </StyledNavListItem>
  )
}
```

But, when trying to unit test it here (with Jest, enzyme and jest-styled-components):

```
it('should change the background color of an item if `props.selected` is truthy', () => {
    const navList = mount(
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route>
            <NavList>
              <NavListItem>item text</NavListItem>
              <NavListItem selected>item text</NavListItem>
            </NavList>
          </Route>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
    expect(navList.find(StyledNavListItem).at(0)).toHaveStyleRule('background', '#e0e0e0')
    expect(navList.find(StyledNavListItem).at(1)).toHaveStyleRule('background', theme.palette.backgrounds.selected)
  })
```

I get the error message `Property not found: "background"`
If I remove the '&&' wrapper from my styles, the tests pass with no problem, but then I don't get the styles to work on the component. Is there any way to reach into that override block to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution -- by specifying custom classes in the material-ui component, then referencing it in the styles, it tests fine with a modifier attached

**Example**
Typography.style.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { withTheme } from 'material-ui/styles'
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography'

export const StyledTypography = withTheme()(styled(({emphasized, strong, inlined, color, ...other}) => {
  return <Typography {...other} classes={{root: 'typography-root'}} />
})`
  &.typography-root {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    ${props => !props.variant && css`
      font-size: 1em;
    `}
    ${props => props.color && props.theme.palette.typography[props.color] && css`
      color: ${props.theme.palette.typography[props.color]};
    `}
    ${props => props.strong && css`
      font-weight: 500;
    `}
    ${props => props.emphasized && css`
      font-style: italic;
    `}
    ${props => props.inlined && css`
      display: inline-block;
    `}
  }
`)
```

**Test**

```
it('does something', () => {
    const typography = mount(
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={praxisTheme}>
        <Typography />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
    expect(typography.find(MaterialUITypography)).toHaveStyleRule('line-height', '1.2em', { modifier: '&.typography-root' })
  })
```